# How to prevent Ruby's YAML parser from trying to parse {{var-name}}

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a bunch of concourse pipeline files that look like the following:

```
---
resources:
  - name: example
    type: git
    source:
      uri: git@github.internal.me.com:me/example.git
      branch: {{tracking_branch}}
      private_key: {{ssh_key}}
      paths:
        - code/src/do/teams/sampleapp
      params:
        depth: 1

  - name: deploy-image
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: {{docker_image_url}}
```

And I want to parse them in ruby to perform a bunch of transformations (like validating them and updating some keys if they are missing).

Problem is, whenever I try to load and them dump them back to files the pieces that have `{{something}}` become:

```
branch:
  ? tracking_branch: 
  : 
private_key:
  ? ssh_key: 
  :
```

Why is it doing this and is there any way I can configure the parser not to do this? Just leave these variables as they are?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflict with YAML's internal syntax you need to quote your values:

```
---
resources:
  - name: example
    type: git
    source:
      uri: git@github.internal.me.com:me/example.git
      branch: '{{tracking_branch}}'
      private_key: '{{ssh_key}}'
      paths:
        - code/src/do/teams/sampleapp
      params:
        depth: 1
```

This sort of thing comes up in [Ansible](http://ansible.com) configuration files all the time for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The `{` and `}` characters are used in Yaml for [flow mappings](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790832) (i.e. hashes). If you don’t provide a value for a mapping entry you get `nil`.

So in the case of `branch: {{tracking_branch}}`, since there are *two* pairs of braces, you get a hash with a key `branch` and value (in Ruby) of

```
{{"tracking_branch"=>nil}=>nil}
```

When this is dumped back out to Yaml you get the somewhat awwkward and verbose:

```
branch:
  ? tracking_branch:
  :
```

The solution is simply to quote the value:

```
branch: "{{tracking_branch}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely forgot that concourse now offers `((var-name))` for templating, just switched to that instead of `{{var-name}}` at the pipelines and the YAML parser is now happy!